# Making many SqlConnections in webforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, webforms

Because I have to constantly make database calls to get data to show in repeaters and modals I have to repeat code in every page multiple times like this and just looks plain dirty

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{ 
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
      {
          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(),
          // End
       }
}
```

For inserting or updating or get datatables... As the project grows it becomes hard to track every single connection specially when an exception happens and there's so many of these in every page on code behind that the code just becomes dirty and a pain to look at.

My question... Is there a more efficient way to get database calls? I have been reading about entity framework and already tried the whole tutorial on microsoft docs and seems pretty nice and neat looking and easy to find things but also seems hard to implement when there are many tables  'cause have to update code whenever have to change database and do migrations and vice versa so rather than just updating database, have to do both.

Also another question, is it fine If i never close my connection on using statements because they close it? I think i avoid just to not make the program waste resources calling an extra fuction to do the same thing or is there any difference if i close the connection after executing the command?

Comment: You can arrange code into classes and methods an endless number of ways.  What specifically is the problem you're looking to solve?  If you have a single form with an unwieldy amount of code then you should refactor into smaller and more manageable objects.  That has nothing to do with your database code, but just how you organize code in general.

Comment: You mean I should just create classes for things that I have to use very often like for example, one requisition class with methods like GetAllRequisitions to get data from database etc?

Comment: In general, yes.  Ideally you'd abstract something like database connections behind simple methods.  There's no single piece of advice to cover the endless ways in which you can organize code.  Though it sounds like you may get some use out of refactoring patterns: https://refactoring.com/

Comment: Regarding `Close`, it's perfectly fine to let the `using` take care of that for you.

Comment: The description of your problem is too vague. What is "all the time"? What is "many data" and why would that be "hard to implement" with Entity Framework? And why should you *repeat* code if it needs to run in multiple locations? Also, stick to one question per post. The second question is equally vague by the way. The very idea of closing connections is not to waste (leak) resources.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I think the option that matches my needs is just continue with ADO.NET and create classes with methods to get data and use Data Annotations for validation rather than implementing the Entity Framework ORM which is a bit costly resource wise.